# Is it possible to use star expression inside array_agg(struct expressions in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, nested-table, array-agg

I am joining several tables into one nested, and I was wondering if I could use a star expression, for example,

```
SELECT t1.*, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(t2.*)) FROM t1 JOIN t2 on t1.col1=t2.col1 GROUP BY t1.*
```

I get an error, but I was wondering, maybe I could use some trick for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your example:

1. `ARRAY_AGG` is an an [aggregate function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions), and as such requires a `GROUP BY` clause.
2. The interior of your `ARRAY_AGG` needs a `SELECT` - i.e., `ARRAY_AGG((SELECT AS STRUCT t2.*))`. The extra parentheses are needed to treat the inside query as a scalar subquery expression.

If you fix those it should be able to run, although I would also suggest aliasing the `ARRAY_AGG` field to make it more readable.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, Jameses answer appears before yours..I cannot mark both as correct :( Thank you for your help!

Comment: No worries - since you're unlikely to get a response to your follow-up (pretty sure James is a bot), no, there's no easy way to group by all columns. There are some convoluted methods you can use, but in most cases the easiest things is to just write out `GROUP BY 1, 2, 3 ...` manually

Comment: haha :) Thank you for the answer! I don't really like these 1,2,3..I think it easy to make a mistake...will just write all my 20 columns then :)

Comment: @MStikh 2 things to note: this answer actually appeared about 2 minutes earlier (you can check the [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68814658/timeline) to see, keeping in mind that it's in reverse chronological order).  That makes me suspect the other answer was copied from this, especially given that it's just had a spam link edited into it.  I'd consider switching the accepted answer over to this.  The other answer is now gone, as it was spam.